# Ajax call with state in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

This will render add.jade. But I prefer to do a better experience UX, so I will use ajax call to the end point. However my url will still be `localhost:3000/books`, not localhost:3000/books/add which there's no state (history), for user to navigate using the browser's back and forth button.

```
router.get('/add', function(req, res) {
        res.render('book/add');
});
```

Comment: Can't you either make the route (server-side) `/books/add` or set the push state manually to show as `/books/add`?

Comment: @AshleyB push state have to do manually right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use history api to change your location. For example, do this in your browser after ajax call:

```
  history.pushState(null, null, '/books/add')
```

Comment: Regular schema is: make ajax call, place rendered html into your page, change location url using pushState. And that's it.